# External drive stopped working after changing the hostname in Raspbian

Tags: external-hard-drive, ntfs, raspberry-pi, raspbian, plex

My external hard drive was working seamlessly for months now with Plex (NTFS), but now I have 5 Raspberry Pis and I wanted to individually name them all.

So I changed this specific Raspberry Pi 4 to `raspi4b-1` and — suddenly — my hard drive was gone. The drive is connected via USB.

I mapped it to `/disks/plex` on my fstab and now it is not showing on `fdisk`, `blkid` nor on `mount -l`.

I don´t know what to do anymore, but I put the drive on Windows and MiniTool Partition Wizard recognizes it, and now I just put it on another Raspberry Pi 4 4b I got, and the drive shows up with all the files and everything!

I have tried setting the  hostname back to `raspberrypi` but it did not work.

I tried `chown pi:pi /disks/plex` but did not work.

I also, I just tried another USB drive and a USB flash drive and it seems my USB connectivity on this one Raspberry Pi is gone: None of the devices are showing up in either `blkid`, `fdisk` or `df`.

For the record, I tried using a USB mouse and a USB keyboard and they were not working either. So this clearly was not a hardware issue because after formatting SD card and reinstalling the system everything is back on.

I also remembered that I made a `sudo apt full-upgrade` that may have caused all of this, much more likely than a hostname change for sure.

What else could I have done other than a full OS reinstall to solve this issue?

Comment: How does the drive connect to the Raspberry Pi? USB? Network mount?

Comment: USB, I just tried another drive and a pendrive, it seems my USB is gone, none of them are showing up on either blkid, fdisk or df

Comment: To test if the USB port is the issue, try connecting a USB device that is not a drive — like a keyboard or mouse — and see what happens. If those devices are not recognized, then it might be the case that the USB port itself is physically damaged or something is up in the OS for some reason. I don’t think a hostname change could do this and it might all just be sadly coincidental.

Comment: I feel stupid for not trying this, but yes, mouse and keyboard are not working too... usbs are dead for sure

Comment: Well, if that’s the case my best advice is to recommend you delete this question. Maybe bookmark it for recovery if you find out something new in the future, but honestly I don’t think there’s much benefit associating the hostname with the USB failure now. Sorry about this. But happy to assist you coming to this conclusion.

Comment: I really think it´s software though (mouse lights up and also drives), I have a berry boot on, so I will install another system and see what happens

Comment: Berryboot no mouse and keyboard either, I will use ssh to get all the files I need and reinstall anything, thanks for the help

Comment: Well, if reinstalling the OS works my recommendation would be to post that experience as an answer but also reiterate the question briefly like: “This clearly was not a hardware issue. What else could I have done other than a full OS reinstall to solve this issue?”

Comment: Just formatted SD card and mouse and keyboard are back, I will reiterate the question as you suggested but will not answer it myself

Comment: have you followed exactly these steps?:https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/change-the-hostname-of-your-pi/

Comment: yes I used raspi-config, but I just updated my question because I remembered doing a full-upgrade before rebooting, and that looks more likely to be the source of the problem